# interchanging limits and derivatives: Terence Tao real analysis example

Tags: real-analysis

I picked up the Analysis 1 book by Terence Tao and was just going through it casually and I came across this example in the very first chapter which has me confused.

The example is about interchanging limits and derivatives. It does not yet start to discuss what things we need to consider when we want to do this. So, the example goes (I am reproducing verbatim)

Observe that if $\epsilon$ > 0, then:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{x^3}{\epsilon^2 + x^2}\bigg) = \frac{3x^2(\epsilon^2 + x^2) - 2x^4}{(\epsilon^2 + x^2)^2}
$$

and in particular,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{x^3}{\epsilon^2 + x^2}\bigg) \bigg|_{x=0} = 0
$$

Taking limits as $\epsilon \to 0$, one might expect that:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{x^3}{0 + x^2}\bigg) \bigg|_{x=0} = 0
$$

But the RHS is $\frac{d}{dx}x = 1$. Does this mean it is always illegitimate to interchange limits and derivatives?

So my question is where has the limit interchange occured? So, just to clarify we are only looking at the function, for the purposes of this exercise, at $x = 0$?

Does the third step mean, we are actually doing the following:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\bigg(\frac{x^3}{\epsilon^2 + x^2}\bigg)\bigg|_{x=0}\bigg) \bigg|_{x=0} = 0
$$

So, as $\epsilon \to 0$, the inside expression tends to $0$ at $x = 0$? Is this understanding correct?

I am very confused by the jump from the second to the third equation where he took the limit.

Comment: Recall $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$ that's where the second limit comes from.

Comment: In the third equation, $\epsilon^2=0$ is where the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$ was taken before the derivative. In the first two cases, the derivative was taken first.